# Powershell script to convert wav files using ffmpeg, no such file error

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg, powershell

I'm using a powershell script to convert some wav files from 24bits per sample with samplerate 48kHz to wav with 16bits per sample and samplerate 16kHz.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse . | ForEach-Object {
    $extension = [IO.path]::GetExtension($_)
    $path = $_.FullName

    if ($extension -eq ".wav") {
        #echo $_
        echo "PATH: $path"
        echo "NAME: $_"
        echo "NEW:  a$_"
        ffmpeg -i "$path" -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 "a$path" -y 
    }
}
```

If I echo the path, it exists. Ffmpeg says

```
filename.wav: No such file or directory
```

Any idea?
I'm a powershell noob, it's probably something obvious.

Comment: I don't know a thing about ffmpeg, I'm afraid, but why on earth would you hard-clamp an audio file to 16KHz without at least pre-EQing everything above 7.5KHz right out? It's going to sound atrocious. If you're doing it just to save file size, consider mp3.

Comment: I really don't care about audio quality right now. However when I get ffmpeg to run, I'll start caring, and will read into what you're saying :)

Comment: I'm not hard clamping, I'm re-sampling. I think?

Comment: Yes - but you're resampling right down into the high frequencies, right where the s's & t's etc are, without any pre-shaping. That's just going to generate absolute cutoff at 8k with no attempt to mitigate it. If you are doing it for data size, that's really not the way to do it, look at compressed audio formats instead.

Comment: Cut-off at 8kHz is fine, I don't need higher frequencies.

Comment: You're *really* not getting my point. Anyway, you'll find out once you try it.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but this audio won't be listened to, just fed into a neural network. Research suggests that frequencies above 5k are useless for what I'm looking for - they don't contain any relevant information. So cut-off is really quite fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem in your output file full name.
e.g. `C:\your\path\filename.wav` would be `aC:\your\path\filename.wav`.

If your output file is `C:\your\path\afilename.wav`,

```
ffmpeg -i "$path" -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 ('"' + (split-path -path $path) + "\a" + $_.name + '"') -y
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I can't upvote. I just solved my problem, installed ubuntu on wsl and used bash to do it, hopefully next time I'll manage to do it in powershell.

Comment: You may try bash on Windows next time.